# Xcode 13 command line replacement for 'instruments -w' to run on a real iOS device with a template

Tags: ios, command-line-interface, instruments

Apple removed the instruments tool from Xcode 13 without further hint how to perform this command on the device:

```
instruments -w -t <tracetemplate>
```

Any hint how to launch a compiled iOS app 'as is' from the command line?

Answer (score 3):

I can run an application on the device with:

```
xcrun xctrace record --template <tracetemplate> --device <deviceUDID> --launch <path to MyApp.app>
```

More information, including some samples, is given with:

```
xcrun xctrace help record
```

A template which doesn't collect loads of data (in case one wants a simple on device starter helper) is the "App Launch" template:

```
xcrun xctrace record  --launch build/iphoneos/abc.app --template "App Launch" --time-limit 24h --device <yourdevice>
```

this keeps the app running and isn't filling the hard disk with tons of data.